# NSMenuItem target and action

Tags: objective-c, action, target, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I would like to have help about binding a function to NSMenuItem.

I have an array of object Tab and I would like to draw an NSMenuItem for each of the Tab objects. I succeed in drawing and adding the NSMenuItem but I would like that when user clicks on the item, it calls the instance method `(void)play` of the concerned Tab object. I've already tried with the following code but it seems to not be working because the menu item stays grey.

```
-(void)buildInterface: (NSMutableArray *) tabArray ;
{
   for (Tab *currentTab in tabArray)
   {
      NSMenuItem *item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
      [item setTitle:@"test"];
      [item setTarget:currentTab];
      [item setAction: @selector(play:)];

      [statusMenu insertItem:item atIndex:1]; 
   } 
}
```

Here is the Tab.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Safari.h"
#import "GoogleChrome.h"

    @interface Tab : NSObject{

        NSString *plistKey; //key pour le dico de la plist
        NSString *navigateur; //type du navigateur
        NSString *titreTab; //titre de la page Web concernée (hors transmission information)
        NSString *idSite; //nom en toute lettre et mis en forme du site
        NSString *URL;  //URL de l'onglet
        NSInteger *tempsChanson; //durée de la chanson courante en seconde 
        NSInteger *tempsPlayed; //temps déjà joué en secondes
        NSInteger *tabIndex; //index de l'onglet
        SafariTab *tabObjectSafari; //objet de l'onglet concerné, safari
        SafariWindow *tabWindowSafari; //fenêtre de l'onglet conderné, safari
        SafariApplication *applicationSafari;
        GoogleChromeTab *tabObjectChrome;
        GoogleChromeWindow *tabWindowChrome;
        GoogleChromeApplication *applicationChrome;

    }
@property(readwrite, copy) NSString *titreTab;
@property(readwrite, copy) NSString *plistKey;
@property(readwrite, copy) NSString *idSite;
@property(readwrite, copy) NSString *URL;
@property(readwrite, copy) NSString *navigateur;
@property(readwrite, retain) SafariTab *tabObjectSafari;
@property(readwrite, retain) SafariWindow *tabWindowSafari;
@property(readwrite, retain) SafariApplication *applicationSafari;
@property(readwrite, retain) GoogleChromeTab *tabObjectChrome;
@property(readwrite, retain) GoogleChromeWindow *tabWindowChrome;
@property(readwrite, retain) GoogleChromeApplication *applicationChrome;

//initialisation d'un onglet Safari
-(id)initwithSafari: (SafariWindow *) passedWindow tab: (SafariTab *)passedTab application:(SafariApplication *)safariApplication dictionnaryKey:(NSString *) plistKey;

//TODO initialisation d'un onglet avec Google Chrome
-(id)initwithChrome: (GoogleChromeWindow *) passedWindow tab: (GoogleChromeTab *)passedTab application:(GoogleChromeApplication *)chromeApplication dictionnaryKey:(NSString *) plistKey;

-(void)play;
+(NSArray *)isControlabe: (SafariTab *) passedTab;

@end
```

Here is the link to a picture showing the result after calling the function
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/3/capturedcran20111127205.png/
(I don't have enough reputation sorry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `[item setAction: @selector(play:)];` which requires a function `-(void)play:(id)sender;`. You should remove the colon in the selector, so that you can use the function `-(void)play;`.